# google sheets script submit button not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, userform

Hay!

im new to javascript and building userforms and ive been following tutorials and reading up where i can to achieve what im wanting to create.

Ive got a mate who has made these and hes had no issues following a tutorial he sent me and ive followed it to the dot on multiple attempts and it all works up until i create the script in the html file and send across through the java script google.script.run

for some reason, it just will not send accross and im not the greatest at debugging. i understand how to do it on the .gs side but the html side doesnt seem to have any and ive been told to use the dev tools from the browser but i still am not sure how to get it to fully work.

Ill post the code below and hopefully someone can spot where im going wrong. also if you can explain why it didnt work and why your way is the solution i would greatly appreciate it as itll help more on my journey to understand everything.
Cheers.

**funcs.gs**

```
function addNewRow(data){

 const date = new Date();
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Compensations");
 
 ws.appendRow([date,data.rubio,data.staff,data.steam,data.steamID,]);
}
```

**AddForm.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Compensation Form</h1>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="staffName">Staff Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Big Cahoonas" aria-label="staffName" aria-describedby="staffName">
      </div> 

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="steamName"> Compensated Steam Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GetRiggityRekt" aria-label="steamName" aria-describedby="steamName">
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="steamID">SteamID64</span>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="76938475322" aria-label="steamID" aria-describedby="steamID">
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="rubioLink">Rubio Link</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rubioLink" placeholder="fivem.ozzy.life/id/1563423" aria-describedby="rubioLink">
      </div>

      <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>







    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",addRecord);

function addRecord(){

var staff = document.getElementById("staffName");
var steam = document.getElementById("steamName");
var steamID = document.getElementById("steamID");
var rubio = document.getElementById("rubioLink");

var data = {
  staff: staff.value,
  steam: steam.value,
  steamID: steamID.value,
  rubio: rubio.value
  };

google.script.run.addNewRow(data);
```

**loadUserForm.gs**

```
function loadForm() {

  const showPop = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AddForm");
  const htmlOutput = showPop.evaluate();

 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Compensation V1");
  
}

function createMenu(){

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu("Compensations");
menu.addItem("Add Record","loadForm");
menu.addToUi();

}

function onOpen(){

createMenu();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your HTML, the ID for each input tag is not set. By this, each value of `data` is `undefined`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So, for example, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="staffName">Staff Name</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Big Cahoonas" aria-label="staffName" aria-describedby="staffName">
</div> 

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="steamName"> Compensated Steam Name</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GetRiggityRekt" aria-label="steamName" aria-describedby="steamName">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="steamID">SteamID64</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="76938475322" aria-label="steamID" aria-describedby="steamID">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="rubioLink">Rubio Link</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rubioLink" placeholder="fivem.ozzy.life/id/1563423" aria-describedby="rubioLink">
</div>
```

#### To:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">Staff Name</span>
  <input type="text" id="staffName" class="form-control" placeholder="Big Cahoonas" aria-label="staffName" aria-describedby="staffName">
</div> 

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"> Compensated Steam Name</span>
  <input type="text" id="steamName" class="form-control" placeholder="GetRiggityRekt" aria-label="steamName" aria-describedby="steamName">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">SteamID64</span>
  <input type="number" id="steamID" class="form-control" placeholder="76938475322" aria-label="steamID" aria-describedby="steamID">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">Rubio Link</span>
  <input type="text" id="rubioLink" class="form-control" id="rubioLink" placeholder="fivem.ozzy.life/id/1563423" aria-describedby="rubioLink">
</div>
```

- In this modification, as a sample modification, in order to use the IDs of your Javascript `addRecord()`, the IDs of `span` were moved to `input`.
- By above modification, when the values are inputted to each input tags and the button is clicked, `data` has the values and your Google Apps Script appends new row with the inputted values to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: hay @tanaike I've tried the amended changes with no success. i appreciate the added information on why its better. just some added information, when clicking submit, its not erasing the fields like I've supplied so i'm running with the assumption that its getting hung up somewhere. still cant find out where though.

Comment: @Mr Lispy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. Because in my environment, I confirmed that the modified script works. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your current script reflected my proposal for replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm your current situation. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: those are the 3 files i currently use for the project so you can host those 3 files and itll run the same as what i have.

In regards to hosting what youve added, ive replaced it so its the exact same. it might be worth running those 3 files i have posted already and seeing if it runs for you as i know on the tutorial there was a very minor amount of people that seemed to have the same issue as im experiencing but the author of the youtube video never commented any solution, this im stuck and have come here in hopes of some form of answer.

Comment: @Mr Lispy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, in my environment, I confirmed that the modified script works. So I thought that it is required to confirm your current whole script for replicating your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Mr Lispy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, in my environment, I confirmed that the modified script works. So I thought that it is required to confirm your current whole script for replicating your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: This is my whole script. still doesnt work for me with your changes.

Comment: @Mr Lispy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From `This is my whole script. still doesnt work for me with your changes.`, I cannot see your current script which reflected my answer. If you can provide your current script which reflected my answer, please add it to your question. You can do it by clicking ["Edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66309830/edit) button of your question. By this, I would like to confirm your current issue from your current script.

Comment: @MrLispy, I was also able to execute the script properly with the changes suggested by Tanaike. Did you close the HTML tags accordingly?

Comment: yeh all sorted, now on a new issue haha